# Problem understanding a proof in Model Categories by Hovey

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, model-categories

I have serious problems understanding this proof from the book *Model Categories*, by Mark Hovey:

[image]
[image]

Here's a list of things I don't understand:

1. He's trying to prove the assertion by contradiction, by showing that there is a sequence in $f(A)$ (which is compact) with no limit point. Thus he should prove that $S$ is discrete in the subspace topology and **is closed as a subset of $f(A)$** (only discreteness wouldn't be sufficient, indeed the sequence $\{1/n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{R}$ has the discrete topology as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ and $0$ as a limit point). Hovey claims to have proven discreteness, but I don't seeany proof of closeness.
2. I don't understand why $S$ should have the discrete topology as a subspace of $X_\mu$.

Any help in understanding the proof would be gratly appreciated.

---

NOTES:

- A *closed $T_1$ inclusion* is defined as an inclusion $f:X\rightarrow Y$ (so, $U\subseteq X$ is open if, and only if, there is some $V\subseteq Y$ such that $f^{-1}(V) = U$) which is also a closed map as such that every point in $Y\backslash f(X)$ is closed.

Comment: Could you kindly tell me that what is the relation between $f(A)$ and $X_\mu$? Maybe then I can answer the second question?

Comment: @Paul: I don't think there is necessarily some relation. The best thing I can say right now is that $f(A)\cap X_\mu$ is compact (since $X_\mu$ is closed). If I find anything else I'll let you know.

Comment: I see. Wait for a memont.

Comment: Hovey argues that *every* subset of $S$ is closed in $X_\mu$.

Comment: @Martin: I don't see it. He says that if $S'\subseteq S$, then $S'\cap X_{\alpha_n}$ is closed in $X_{\alpha_n}$, and this is certainly true by construction of $S$. How would that imply that $S$ is closed in $X_\mu$?

Comment: Since $\mu$ is the limit of the $\alpha_n$ and you started with a $\lambda$-sequence, $X_\mu$ carries the final topology of the inclusions $X_{\alpha_n} \to X_{\mu}$. A subset of $X_\mu$ is closed iff it is closed in all $X_{\alpha_n}$.

Comment: @Martin: Ah! Thank you, I didn't think of that. I think it's possible to answer the whole question working on that. Write your comment as an answer and if I get to the solution that way I'll accept it as the good answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption that the $X_\alpha$ form a $\lambda$-sequence includes in particular that for every limit ordinal $\kappa \leq \lambda$ we have $X_\kappa = \varinjlim_{\alpha \lt \kappa} X_\alpha$.

Since directed colimits are unchanged by passing to cofinal subsets of the indexing set, we have $X_\mu = \varinjlim_{\alpha_n} X_{\alpha_n}$. In other words, $X_\mu$ carries the final topology  induced by the system $X_{\alpha_0} \to X_{\alpha_1} \to \cdots$. This implies that a subset $B$ of $X_\mu$ is closed iff $X_{\alpha_n} \cap B$ is closed in $X_{\alpha_n}$ for all $n$.

Hovey argues that for *every* subset $S' \subseteq S$ we have that $X_{\alpha_n} \cap S'$ is closed in *every* $X_{\alpha_n}$ (since it is finite and contained in $X_{\alpha_n} \setminus X_{\alpha_0}$), so $S'$ is closed in $X_\mu$. This applies in particular to $S$ itself, so $S$ is closed in $X_{\mu}$ and since every subset $S' \subseteq S$ is closed in $X_\mu$, it follows that $S$ is discrete.

On the other hand, the map $X_\mu \to X_\lambda = \varinjlim_{\alpha \lt \lambda} X_\alpha$ is a closed inclusion, so every subset $S'$ of $S$ is also closed in $X_\lambda$. Since every subset of $S$ is closed in $X_\lambda$, we have that $S$ is an infinite closed discrete subset of the compact space $f(A) \subseteq X_\lambda$, which is impossible.

Comment: To show that $S$ is discrete, is it correct to say that it is the colimit of $S\cap X_{\alpha_n}$ (with subspace topology), and to use the same argument to obtain opens around every element?

Comment: How do you know *a priori* that $S$ is the colimit of the $X_{\alpha_n} \cap S$? In general, colimits do not interact well with subspaces, so you could only say that the subspace topology of $S$ as a subspace of $X_\mu$ is coarser than the colimit topology it gets from the $S \cap X_{\alpha_n}$, which in this case tells us nothing since the latter is discrete...

Comment: Ok, but then how do you know that $S$ is discrete? I really don't get it.

Comment: I show that *every* subset of $S$ is closed which amounts to saying that every subset of $S$ is open (by taking complements), so $S$ is discrete.

Comment: Aaah! Wow I feel stupid now! Thank you a lot for your help :D

Comment: Ah, the penny dropped :) No worries, Hovey had me confused for a moment, too. // I agree with you that this argument could have been written up more clearly. In particular, the contradiction is not correct the way it is written. Of course, there can be discrete subspaces of compact spaces.

Answer (score 0):

1) I will prove a general result:

**Result 1:** Let $X$ be a $T_1$ space and $S$ be a subset of $X$. If $S$ hasn't an accumulation, then it is closed and discrete.

**Proof:**  **$S$ is closed:** since $\overline{S}=S\cup S'$ and $S'=\emptyset$, then $\overline{S}=S$. **$S$ is discrete:** for any point $s\in S$, there exists an open set $U$ of $s$ such that $U\cap S$ is finite (Why?), say $\{s_i: 1\le n\}$, and hence $s$ has an open set $O=U \cap \{U_i:i\le n\}$ such that $O\cap S=\{s\}$, which witnesses that $S$ is discrete, where each $U_i$ is an nbhd of $s$ such that $x_i \notin U_i$. This complete the proof.

2) Since $S$ is discrete, there exaist $\{U_s: s\in S\}$ of $f(A)$ such that $U_s \cap S=\{s\}$. To prove that $S$ is discrete in the $X_\mu$ as the subsapce of $X_\mu$. Just let $V_s=U_s \cap X_\mu$. Then $\{V_s: s\in S\}$ is the family of open sets of $X_\mu$ witnesses that $S$ is discrete in the $X_\mu$.

Comment: Yes, I know this result, but I don't see how it is relevant to the proof, since we want to prove that $S$ has no accumulation point.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: Do you want to prove that $S$ has no accumulation point?

Comment: Yes, the proof is by contradiction, if I'm not mistaken in my understanding. We start with $A$ a compact space, and we show that there is a sequence $S$ in $f(A)$ (which is compact again) with no accumulation point, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: Wnat is a closed inclusive in your question?

Comment: I have added the definition to the question.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: I will take some time to consider it. If I cannot answer, I will delete my present answer.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your time and effort :)